# Line Separator not displaying on device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seprator.png"]];
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:color];
```

this works fine on simulator but the image is not displaying on device.

Comment: did you try adding separator and separator color in the xib?

Comment: Please check spelling of seprator.png

Comment: Also check the case for seprator.png

Comment: every thing is alright when i use this image any where else it works fine

Comment: Remove `.png` from the image name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
[self.tableView setBackgroudView:nil];
```

Then

```
[theTableView.setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project command+shift+K in your device (choose the device in XCode) and then run the project again so that the image will copy in the running build in your device.